# shell/bash while read export variable not working for subtitute

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sh

I want export variable from file. here's my file

```
cat file.txt
VERSION=1.0.0
LOCATION=USA
NAME=sample
ENVIRONMENT=$ENV
```

I export all variable on that file using this while loop

```
while read vars; do export $vars;done < file.txt
```

all variable is successfully exported, except `ENVIRONMENT`
i got this value, `ENVIRONMENT=$ENV` (expected value is `ENVIRONMENT=staging`) .

```
printenv | grep ^ENV
ENV=staging
```

my question is, why substitute it's not working when using `while loop`, but its working if we manually export `(e.g export ENVIRONMENT=$ENV)` ??

actually there's many ways, to export variable from file, for example I can use `envsubst < file > file1` and then do the `while loop`, but I just need explanation for case above.

Comment: Why won't you just use `source`? Or `.` in case of `sh`? Just do `source file.txt` and all variables will be in your environment

Comment: because it won't work if there's `#` in file

Comment: Eh? `source` runs through the regular parser so it skips comments just fine. What do you mean "won't work if there's `#` in file"?

Comment: Mind, if you want to `export` things, you'll want to enable auto-export before sourcing the file. `set -a; . file.txt; set +a` and there you are.

Comment: @TarasKhalymon, caveat: `source file.txt` is just setting regular shell variables, not environment variables, unless `file.txt` contains `export` directives or `set -a` is enabled.

Comment: @Fixlensmith, `ENVIRONMENT=$ENV` isn't going to expand `$ENV` in the `do export $vars` case -- where/why/how would you expect it to?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, yes..you can try, if there's comment `#` in file, `$ENV` will not expanded

Comment: @Fixlensmith, that's provably untrue. See https://replit.com/@CharlesDuffy2/LastSerpentinePython#main.sh -- the file has comments, `$ENV` is still expanded.

Comment: @Fixlensmith, ...could I ask you to provide an example that shows contrary behavior?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, my mistake, it working after i add `set -a` .. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The order of expansions are [described in POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_02):

> The order of word expansion shall be as follows:
>
> 1. Tilde expansion (see Tilde Expansion), parameter expansion (see Parameter Expansion), command substitution (see Command Substitution), and arithmetic expansion (see Arithmetic Expansion) shall be performed, beginning to end. See item 5 in Token Recognition.
> 2. Field splitting (see Field Splitting) shall be performed on the portions of the fields generated by step 1, unless IFS is null.
> 3. Pathname expansion (see Pathname Expansion) shall be performed, unless set -f is in effect.
> 4. Quote removal (see Quote Removal) shall always be performed last.

For Parameter Expansion, the tl;dr is:

> ${parameter}
>
> The value, if any, of parameter shall be substituted.

You will notice that the definition is not recursive or multi-pass. There is no "5. Go back to step 1 and repeat until no further expansions can be performed", or "The value, if any, of parameter shall be substituted, and the process repeated until no more parameter expansions can be found."

This means that `export $vars` will expand `$vars` in step 1,  but will not repeat that step and therefore leave `$ENV` alone.

This is also how basically all other programming languages work, e.g. Java:

```
String foo="bar";
String bar="baz";
// Prints `bar` without recursively resolving it into `baz`
System.out.println(foo);
```